# Windows 7 fails to start, even after HD wipe and reinstall

Tags: windows-7, boot, filesystems

**Laptop cannot boot into Windows 7 or a Windows 7 repair environment.**

Symptom started in the middle of data transfer to a USB device.

- **Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit**
- Samsung NP-R580H Laptop

---

## Attempts to boot

### Startup options

- **Safe mode**
  Fails or goes to blank GUI w/ cursor.
- **Disable automatic restart on system failure**
  Reboots, no BSOD.
- **Enable boot logging**
  No `ntbtlog.txt` created.

### Hard Drive

- **Wiped with `shred`**
  Single pass, all 0's
- **Reinstalled Windows 7**
  From Samsung restore DVD's.
- **SMART diagnostics**
  Claims it's healthy.

### BIOS

- **Reset defaults**
- **Disabled CD drive**
  Didn't help boot.
- **Outdated** (08JB vs 11JB)
  Can't run update executable.

### Memory

- **Windows Memory Test**
  Pass
- **Memtest86+**
  Pass

### Boot Disks

- **Windows 7 Install** (USB image)
  Reboots on "Starting Windows" screen.
- **32-bit Windows 7 Recovery** (USB image)

  - **System Recovery**
    Aborts with "incorrect Windows version"
  - **Command prompt**
    Works.
  - **Startup Repair**
    Fails to fix, or shows 'Report Problem' dialog.
- **64-bit Windows 7 Recovery** (USB image)
  Shows "Windows is loading files", reboots
- **Ubuntu 10.04** (USB image)
  Runs without issues.

### Command Line

- **`bootrec`**

  - `/fixmbr`
  - `/fixboot`
  - `/rebuildbcd`
  - `/scanos`

    ```
    Successfully scanned Windows installations.
    Total identified Windows installations: 0
    ```
- **`chkdsk /r`** shows nothing.
- **`sfc /scannow`**

  ```
  There is a system repair pending which requires reboot to continue. Restart
  Windows and run sfc again.
  ```

Comment: Few questions. When you boot from Ubuntu Live USB can you view the hard drive of your PC? Was the BIOS updated to the latest version?

Comment: View HD--yes. I browsed all 4 partitions. SMART diagnostics reported no issues. BIOS is 08JB, latest on Samsung.com appears to be 11JB.

Comment: And I downloaded the BIOS updater, but it doesn't work from the Windows 7 Recovery 32-bit environment (says it couldn't find a battery or it was too low--but it was 100% on AC).

Comment: Other then the restore DVD's, do you have an actual Windows 7 DVD to try?  Does the laptop have a restore partition on the HDD that you can attempt the restore from there rather from the DVD's? Use the Linux CD to rename the \Windows & \Program* directories & try the install again?

Comment: I used the partition first, then used the DVD's after I gave up. I have tried the install at least 4 different ways thus far.

Answer (score 1):

Things to try.

- Run a chkdsk /r
- Reset bios to defaults, then check/set bios date and time, try recovery again.
  Be sure all external devices are disconnected from notebook during Install/Recovery, enable wireless Before recovery starts.
- Try another hard drive if you can.

Comment: Wiped drive completely, reset BIOS, date/time looks good. Reinstalled from recovery. Not able to enable wireless. Would like to try a hard drive but do not have one.

Comment: See if there is a compatibility mode in the bios, or IDE mode, enable that, try the install again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

During the Windows 7 installation when you come to the disk partition point hit `Shift+F10` at the command prompt run through these commands.

1. `diskpart`
2. `list disk`
3. `select disk X`
4. `clean`
5. `create partition primary size=300`
6. `select partition 1`
7. `format fs=ntfs label="System"`
8. `assign letter=S`
9. `active`
10. `create partition primary`
11. `select partition 2`
12. `format fs=ntfs label="Windows"`
13. `assign letter=C`
14. `exit`

Replace **X** in `select disk X` with the number of the hard drive you are going to use found during `list disk`... these commands will wipe the drive and create two partitions the System at 300MB and the C:\ filling the rest of the space.

Then follow through with the installation as normal selecting the created C:\ partition.

Edit: Forgot to tell you that you need to click **Refresh** after you exit the DOS prompt so you can see the newly created partitions.

Comment: Thank you. Before I try this, would you mind explaining two things? (1) What is the intent here by creating them through `diskpart`; and (2) Did you purposefully leave out the ~100MB and additional ~220GB partitions Samsung wants me to create? I really have no idea what the small one is. The big one is probably the (unnecessary) Recovery partition.

Comment: the 100 mb partition is the 'boot' partition

Comment: I generally put more than 100MB just in case.. its not that much space and the only way to do that is through the command line. Some technet documents recommend 300MB so I do that normally. Partitioning your drive manually and not letting the installer do it automatically solves some issues with installation that is why I am suggesting you do it yourself.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by Samsung wanting you to create a 220GB partition that is way larger than any recovery partition should be...